# How to verify XML signature in kotlin?

Tags: java, xml, kotlin, xml-signature, rsa-sha256

I have the value of signature (extracted from the xml data), public key (extracted from a certificate), and the SignedInfo, which i have to canonicalize first. I've bee verifying it but returning an invalid signature, are there any other methods efficient for verifying xml signatures? here is my code:

```
fun verify(signature: String, breadcrumb: Breadcrumb): Boolean {
        return try {
            val canonicalizedSignedInfo = canonicalizeXml(signedInfo)
            val sha256RSA = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA")
            val publicKey = getMcPubKey(breadcrumb)
            sha256RSA.initVerify(publicKey)
            sha256RSA.update(canonicalizedSignedInfo.toByteArray())

            sha256RSA.verify(java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(signature))
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            false
        }
    }



private fun canonicalizeXml(xmlString: String): String = ByteArrayOutputStream().let {
   Canonicalizer
     .getInstance(Canonicalizer.ALGO_ID_C14N_OMIT_COMMENTS)
     .canonicalize(
        xmlString.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8),
        it,
        true
     )
   return it.toString(Charsets.UTF_8)
}
```

Comment: Failure could be that you are using the wrong encryption, the machine you are using doesn't support the encryption mode, or the padding mode of the key is wrong, or you are not encryption the correct section of the file.